# Differentiability class

Tags: functions, derivatives

In what differentiable class of functions does $f(x)$ fall knowing that all its derivatives are undefined at $x=0$, given by:

$$
f(x)=e^{-a|x|}
$$

Where $a>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write, $f$ is *not* differentiable at $0$, which implies that $f$ is not differentiable as a function $\def\R{\mathbf R}\R \to \R$(since one calls a function differentiable iff it is differentiable at every point). Of course, $f$ is differentiable arbitrary often at every other point, so $f$'s restriction $f|_{\R -\{0\}}$ is a $C^\infty$-function, 
$ f|_{\R - \{0\}} \in C^\infty(\R-\{0\})$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks.